# Rails4: Ajax , how to Increase row number during append

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I want to show all categories from category table with row number.
So, if a category has 3 rows, it will show

1. catdfd
2. catgrg
3. categterg

When I click add, it should increase the row number(4,5 ...). I have tried to use rails _counter variable but it does not work with Ajax.

**index.html.erb**

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th >No</th> <--------------No column
      <th >Title</th>
      <th ></th>

    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="appendcat">
<%= render partial: @category %>


</tbody>
</table>
```

**_category.html.erb**

```
 <tr id="caterow_<%=category.id%>">
        <td><%=%></td> <--------------here??
        <td><%=category.parent_title %>  </td>
        <td><%= link_to("Show",   category,:class =>'') %> &nbsp;
<%= link_to("Edit",   edit_category_path(category),:class =>'') %> &nbsp;
<%= link_to("Delete", category_path(category), method: :delete, data:{confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, remote: true )%> &nbsp;  
</td>

</tr>
```

**create.js.erb**

```
$('#appendcat').append('<%= j render(@category)%>');
```

Ajax works fine. I can add a category and it displays new category without refresh. However, As soon as I add `<%=category_counter+1%>` in _category.html.erb, It does not work.

All it want is to increase the row number dynamically. 
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**index.html.erb**
Assumption here is you will get all the existing categories in @categories variable from the index action.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th >No</th>
      <th >Title</th>
      <th ></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="appendcat">
    @categories.each_with_index do  |category, index|
        <%= render partial: category, locals: { category: category, counter: index+1 }  %>
      end
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**_category.html.erb**

```
<tr id="caterow_<%=category.id%>">
  <td><%= counter %></td>
  <td><%=category.parent_title %>  </td>
  <td>
    <%= link_to("Show", category,:class =>'') %> &nbsp;
    <%= link_to("Edit", edit_category_path(category),:class =>'') %> &nbsp;
    <%= link_to("Delete", category_path(category), method: :delete, data:{confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, remote: true)%> &nbsp;  
  </td>
</tr>
```

**create.js.erb**
Assumption here is you will get the new category in @category variable from the create action.

```
$('#appendcat').append('<%= j render partial: 'category', locals: { category: @category, counter: Category.count } %>');
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Category.count solved it partially. When I add new row, it increases the value but, for other row it shows the total value. link 3,3,3,4,5 .ie it has three categories, old rows gets 3, new row 4,5 ...

Comment: Edited the answer and it has everything you need. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thankyou for sharing your knowledge :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
last = parseInt($("#appendcat tr:last td:first").text() );
$('#appendcat').append('<%= j render(@category)%>');
$("#appendcat tr:last td:first").text( last + 1);
```

Comment: You do not need to change view code. Your response is javascript that (1) takes number from last available row, (2) appends new row and then (3) adds 'number + 1' to the added row.